# how to end all ansible playbooks at once. can't do it with module meta

Tags: ansible

i have list of playbooks in site.yml, like this:
- playbook1.yml
- playbook2.yml
in playbook1 i have this module:

```
- hosts: all
  name: failing
  tasks:
  - meta: end_play
    when:
    - fail_trigger == 1
```

But it  ends only playbook1.
Do you know how to end all playbooks in site.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Do you know how to end all playbooks in site.yml?"***

A: A task in a play can't terminate any other play. The module [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) provides `end_host` and `end_play` only. No `end_playbook`.

The only options are to:

- conditionally terminate the plays at the beginning, or
- conditionally skip the importing of playbooks.

Comment: thanks, will try to set fact in first playbook and catch it in others